# Why is 1 not being outputted? (Simple php problem)

Tags: php

I have a question which I don't know the answer of. I've been thinking about it for a while.

The following code:

```
$i = 1;
while($i < 10) 
    if(($i++) % 2 == 0)
    echo $i;
```

It correctly outputs 3579, but why isnt 1 also included in the output?

I'm a beginner with PHP and am looking forward for someone to help me.

Thank you very much! :D

Comment: `echo $1;` TYPO maybe `echo $i;` would work better

Comment: _It correctly outputs 3579.._ How can this be? It throws a **Fatal Error** because of what @RiggsFolly mentioned

Comment: Also try incrementing `$i` AFTER you test it, not before

Comment: @B001ᛦ I am assuminmg thats a accident in the writing of the question :)

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed the code. Now it outputs 3579.

Comment: @RiggsFolly got it :)

Comment: `why isnt 1 also included in the output?` because you are incrementing it `i++` so it becomes 2. use `$i=0;` at the start

Comment: @Ash-b
I see! 2 is obviously not an odd number, so not shown. If it starts at 0 it gets 1, which is. Thanks, I finally understand it! :D

Comment: @Frankeyx: start from `$i = 0;` that is the case. check answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two modifications:

```
$i = 0; // Make it 0 from 1
while($i < 10)
if(($i++) % 2 == 0)
echo "<br/>".$i; // Make $i instead of $1

Output:


1
3
5
7
9
```

**Program hand run:**

1) Set $i to 0.

2) If it is greater than 10, go ahead.

3) Increment it by 1

4) So, for $i => 0->1, 1->2

4) if new $i is even, print it. (So for first loop iteration, you are have $i -> 1 instead of 0 because of `++$i`

Comment: Hmm. Yes, now it does correctly output it, thank you! But, I still do not understand why. I'm not very good at PHP... trying to learn :). Could you explain in text, why it starts at 3 and not 1?

Comment: Because `$i++` gets run before the `%` modulo therefore as you started `%i` at 1 it never saw a 1 the first time `$i` is tested it is already 2

Comment: Yep, got it. Thanks! :)